# Huawei Mobile Services SDK violation Device and Network Abuse policy

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

> Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Device and
> Network Abuse policy. We found your app is using a non-compliant
> version of Huawei Mobile Services SDK which contains code to download
> or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.

**I am using Huawei Mobile Services SDK for Auto Eraser.**

> List of used dependency

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:3.0.0.301'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-body-model:2.0.2.300'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

        //Auto eraser
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300'
    }
}
```

> Added below meta data in manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.huawei.hms.ml.DEPENDENCY"
    android:value="imgseg" />
```

Comment: hi@VIISHRUT MAVANII, Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Comment: and may i confirm have you configured the following metadata in your app？
```<meta-data 
android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket" 
android:value="false" />```

Comment: @shirley I am using it without appId.

Comment: yes@VIISHRUT MAVANII, but before reporting to R&D team, we need to confirm your app ID, app package name, and whether above metadata is configured. Then we will record the information and report it to R&D team to fix it.

Comment: @shirley That's True! but during the whole implementation, SDK didn't ask me for any API key. It is working without any registration. I have followed this blog https://medium.com/huawei-developers/build-a-background-eraser-app-with-huawei-ml-kit-image-segmentation-52208a7471ee

Comment: Or do you know your app package name? You can refer to this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-appinfo-0000001100014694?ha_source=hms1). After a project is created on AppGallery Connect, you can obtain your developer ID, the client ID, and app information including the app ID.

Comment: We received the same warning from google play today. Could it be an issue with the version of com.huawei.agconnect?

Comment: @GareDeveloper, We are very sorry that it brings you inconvinience and are now investigating the root cause of it. Could you mind leave your APPID, app name and package name? and just to confirm, whether configured the following metadata in your app? `<meta-data  android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket"  android:value="false" />`

Comment: No in our manifest there isn't configured such meta-data. Can you explain why is needed? I retrieve the documentation and the problem could be that, as default, the flag is true and the Play Store recognizes the HMS SDK as dangerous?

Comment: We also received the same warning today. Why this issue popped up? Any solution? @shirley

Comment: @UtkuAltaş  sorry, we are now investigating the root cause of it, and will provide a solution as soon as possible. BTW, to better address this issue, could you provide the information that I consulted above? Your appId, etc.

Comment: we got same issue from Play store. I suspect that HMS downloads and installs third app. Because a few days ago, some strange apps were available in my phone even though I didn't install those app and a notification said that x app installed from y(our app) app

Comment: Same issue here, I don't know what should I do :( I'm using Huawei ML kit for too many apps

Comment: Same issue here. We don't have the metadata mentioned in our app. Any idea why we need that? Here's our app: https://appgallery.huawei.com/app/C100433473

Comment: I received the same message today from Google. Now i have 120 days to delete this library from my app. What should we do now Huawei? Using this library to check is Huawei services available on device or not: implementation 'com.huawei.hms:base:6.4.0.300'

Comment: Hello, I can confirm we have the same issue. We use the following libraries :
- MapKit
- LocationKit
- ScanKit
- PushKit
- HiAnalytics

Comment: hi@waseefakhtar, Your request has been received. We are aware of this issue and are currently investigating. Your application experience won't be affected at this time and we will continue to update you on solutions. Thanks for your understanding and support.

Comment: You can follow the conversation on the Huawei dev forums here: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/forum/topic/0201829890037360002?fid=18 it appears the team has acknowledge the issue and is working towards a resolution.

Comment: Hello, still no update on the Huawei forum. Furthermore, reading chinese is not easy for everyone :-)
Is there a status somewhere ?

Comment: Hey @shirley, can you explain what `<meta-data  android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket"  android:value="false" />` exactly does if set to `true` and what it does if set to `false`. It's not quite clear for me from the Configuring Metadata section in [this documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/as-integration-hms-core-sdk-0000001050436235). Thanks in advance

Comment: hi@Vall0n , This is a key-value pair. Do not change it to `true`. Define it based on the integration in the document.
`ActivityInfo actInfo = mContext.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo( 
getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); 
String msg = actInfo.metaData.getString("com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket");
`The default value `false` is used in the SDK. If the value is changed to`true`, the value cannot be matched.

Comment: Hey @shirley, thanks for the fast response! 
And what is the purpose of this key-value pair? I run the code on a pixel 5 and a Huawei CDY-NX9A but the value of `com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket` was always null.

Comment: Facing same issue even in 2023 with all latest SDK.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:**

*Note*:
If you have confirmed that the latest SDK version is used, before submitting a release to Google, please check the apks in all Testing track on Google Play Console(including Open testing, Closed testing, Internal testing). Ensure that the APKs on all tracks(including paused track) have updated to the latest HMS Core SDK.

---

HMS Core SDKs have undergone some version updates recently. To further improve user experience, update the HMS Core SDK integrated into your app to the latest version.

| **HMS Core SDK** | **Version** | **Link** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Keyring | com.huawei.hms:keyring-credential:6.4.0.302 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Security-Guides/version-change-history-0000001179180527) |
| Location Kit | com.huawei.hms:location:6.4.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050986155) |
| Nearby Service | com.huawei.hms:nearby:6.4.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/system-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050040574) |
| Contact Shield | com.huawei.hms:contactshield:6.4.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/system-Guides/version-change-history-0000001058738898) |
| Video Kit | com.huawei.hms:videokit-player:1.0.12.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Media-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050199403) |
| Wireless kit | com.huawei.hms:wireless:6.4.0.202 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/system-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050989943) |
| FIDO | com.huawei.hms:fido-fido2:6.3.0.304 com.huawei.hms:fido-bioauthn:6.3.0.304 com.huawei.hms:fido-bioauthn-androidx:6.3.0.304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Security-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050750051) |
| Panorama Kit | com.huawei.hms:panorama:5.0.2.308 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Media-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050137382) |
| Push Kit | com.huawei.hms:push:6.5.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-app-version-0000001074227861) |
| Account Kit | com.huawei.hms:hwid:6.4.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050048874) |
| Identity Kit | com.huawei.hms:identity:6.4.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050040475) |
| Safety Detect | com.huawei.hms:safetydetect:6.4.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Security-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050156329) |
| Health Kit | com.huawei.hms:health:6.5.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001057072287) |
| In-App Purchases | com.huawei.hms:iap:6.4.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050065947) |
| ML Kit | com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-ocr:3.6.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-cloud:3.5.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-card-icr-cn:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-card-icr-vn:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-card-bcr:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-formrecognition:3.5.0.302 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-translate:3.6.0.312 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-language-detection:3.6.0.312 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-voice-asr:3.5.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-voice-tts:3.6.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-voice-aft:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-voice-realtimetranscription:3.5.0.303 com.huawei.hms:ml-speech-semantics-sounddect-sdk:3.5.0.302 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-classification:3.5.0.302 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-object:3.5.0.307 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:3.5.0.303 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-imagesuperresolution:3.5.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-documentskew:3.5.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-textimagesuperresolution:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-scenedetection:3.6.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-face:3.5.0.302 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-skeleton:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-livenessdetection:3.6.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-interactive-livenessdetection:3.6.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-handkeypoint:3.5.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-faceverify:3.6.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-nlp-textembedding:3.5.0.300 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-ner:3.5.0.301 com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-model-executor:3.5.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/version-changehistory-0000001050040023) |
| Analytics Kit | com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.5.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050705116) |
| Dynamic Tag Manager | com.huawei.hms:dtm-api:6.5.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-android-0000001050043913) |
| Site Kit | com.huawei.hms:site:6.4.0.304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-version-change-history-0000001050156624) |
| HEM Kit | com.huawei.hms:hemsdk:1.0.4.303 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/system-Guides/hem-version-change-history-0000001058818904) |
| Map Kit | com.huawei.hms:maps:6.5.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-version-change-history-0000001050156688) |
| Wallet Kit | com.huawei.hms:wallet:4.0.5.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050042326) |
| Awareness Kit | com.huawei.hms:awareness:3.1.0.302 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050033093) |
| Crash | com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-crash:1.7.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-crash-sdkchangenotes-0000001054941952) |
| APM | com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms:1.5.2.310 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-apm-android-releasenotes-0000001052887266) |
| Ads Kit | com.huawei.hms:ads-prime:3.4.55.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-version-change-history-0000001050066909) |
| Paid Apps | com.huawei.hms:drm:2.5.8.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-paidapps-sdkchangenotes-0000001073783146) |
| Base | com.huawei.hms:base:6.4.0.303 |  |

Required versions for cross-platform app development:

| Platform | Plugin Name | Version | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| React Native | react-native-hms-analytics | 6.3.2-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050159909) |
|  | react-native-hms-iap | 6.4.0-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050726208) |
|  | react-native-hms-location | 6.4.0-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050140226) |
|  | react-native-hms-map | 6.3.1-304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050141050) |
|  | react-native-hms-push | 6.3.0-304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050155836) |
|  | react-native-hms-site | 6.4.0-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050178629) |
|  | react-native-hms-nearby | 6.2.0-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001054140445) |
|  | react-native-hms-account | 6.4.0-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050766267) |
|  | react-native-hms-ads | 13.4.54-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050438945) |
|  | react-native-hms-adsprime | 13.4.54-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050438945) |
|  | react-native-hms-availability | 6.4.0-303 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001137756139) |
| Cordova (Ionic-Cordova Ionic-Capacitor) | cordova-plugin-hms-analytics ionic-native-hms-analytics | 6.3.2-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050134727) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-location ionic-native-hms-location | 6.4.0-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050142197) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-nearby ionic-native-hms-nearby | 6.2.0-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001062262624) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-account ionic-native-hms-account | 6.4.0-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001051086314) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-push ionic-native-hms-push | 6.3.0-304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050135703) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-site ionic-native-hms-site | 6.4.0-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050175533) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-iap ionic-native-hms-iap | 6.4.0-301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001126433215) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-availability ionic-native-hms-availability | 6.4.0-303 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001085863384) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-ads ionic-native-hms-ads | 13.4.54-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050312764) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-adsprime ionic-native-hms-adsprime | 13.4.54-300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050312764) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-map ionic-native-hms-map | 6.0.1-305 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050204329) |
|  | cordova-plugin-hms-ml ionic-native-hms-ml | 2.0.5-303 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001051085722) |
| Flutter | huawei_safetydetect | 6.4.0+301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001061666870) |
|  | huawei_iap | 6.2.0+301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050730646) |
|  | huawei_health | 6.3.0+302 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001074429198) |
|  | huawei_fido | 6.3.0+304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001077561088) |
|  | huawei_push | 6.3.0+304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050417995) |
|  | huawei_account | 6.4.0+301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050726410) |
|  | huawei_ads | 13.4.55+300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050196419) |
|  | huawei_analytics | 6.5.0+300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050171091) |
|  | huawei_map | 6.5.0+301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050190751) |
|  | huawei_hmsavailability | 6.4.0+303 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001128012871) |
|  | huawei_location | 6.0.0+303 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050433501) |
|  | huawei_adsprime | 13.4.55+300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050196419) |
|  | huawei_ml | 3.2.0+301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001051432486) |
|  | huawei_site | 6.0.1+304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050179102) |
| Xamarin | Huawei.Hms.Hianalytics | 6.4.1.302 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050141587) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Location | 6.4.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050140266) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Nearby | 6.2.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001062117591) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Push | 6.3.0.304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050136488) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Site | 6.4.0.300 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050135803) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Fido | 6.3.0.304 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001096426801) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Iap | 6.4.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050767521) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Hwid | 6.4.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001051005767) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Ads-prime | 3.4.54.302 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050176478) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Ads | 3.4.54.302 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050176478) |
|  | Huawei.Hms.Maps | 6.5.0.301 | [Link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050141070) |

If you have any further questions or encounter any issues integrating any of these kits, please feel free to contact us.

| **Region** | **Email** |
| --- | --- |
| Europe | developereu@huawei.com |
| Asia Pacific | developerapac@huawei.com |
| Latin America | developerla@huawei.com |
| Middle East & Africa | developermea@huawei.com |
| Russia | developer_ru@huawei.com |

Comment: I suppose this is the actual change that matters: Improved the capability of prompting users to install HMS Core (this is for In-App Purchases 6.4.0.301 and Identity Kit 6.4.0.301).

Comment: Did anyone tried the latest versions of the HMS SDK and submitted to the PlayStore ?
We worked around the issue for the moment but I would be really interested on having a feedback.

Comment: @nunoarruda i received mail today did you received too? or this workaround worked for you so I will upgrade as above if you haven't received mail today!

Comment: @shirey i recieved email from google "We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Huawei Mobile Services SDK which contains code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play." Are you sure after upgrade as you suggest my issue will fixed?

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment. Yesterday I received another email from Google Play saying my app is not compliant again. I've reopened a GitHub issue related to that: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-cordova-plugin/issues/81

Comment: @KishanSoni nunoarruda  Please check the apk in Testing Track on Google Play Console.   Ensure that the APK on all channels are using of the latest HMS Core SDK version.

Comment: @JohnThiriet did you tried the latest versions and worked with you ?

Comment: We have decided to generate different builds for AppGallery and Google Play Store unfortunately. Therefore, we avoided the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you have dependencies that can be replaced with Google compatible equivalent dependencies then this could be a possible solution to manage both in one code base.

Using app flavours I was able to separate my GMS and HMS dependencies. In your app level `build.gradle` file you can create product flavour like so

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "platforms"
    ...
    productFlavors {
        gms {
            dimension "platforms"
        }
        hms {
            dimension "platforms"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

More on product flavors [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors).
And then you can specify if a dependency should be part of the flavour by prefixing it to the keyword `implementation` under `dependencies`.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    gmsImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    hmsImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.0.0.300'
    ...
}
```

I then went a bit further by wrapping the usage of each dependency in a class that is available in both flavours but the implementation differs based on the dependency's requirements.

```
com.example.maps.MapImpl under src>hms>java
and
com.example.maps.MapImpl under src>gms>java
```

So I am free to use the wrapper class anywhere without worrying about the dependency mismatch.

The HMS dependency is no longer part of the GMS build variant so I would be able to upload that to the Google playstore.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by doing similar to what @Daniel has suggested to avoid such worries in the future:

1. Create different product flavors in your app level Gradle file:

```
android {
    ...

    flavorDimensions 'buildFlavor'

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension 'buildFlavor'
        }

        production {
            dimension 'buildFlavor'
        }


        huawei {
            dimension 'buildFlavor'
        }
    }
}
```

2. Restrict the Huawei related dependencies so they're only available for Huawei product flavor:

```
    huaweiImplementation "com.huawei.hms:iap:3.0.3.300"
    huaweiImplementation "com.huawei.hms:game:3.0.3.300"
    huaweiImplementation "com.huawei.hms:hwid:5.0.1.301"
    huaweiImplementation "com.huawei.hms:push:5.0.0.300"
    huaweiImplementation "com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:5.0.3.300"
    huaweiImplementation "com.huawei.hms:location:5.0.0.301"
```

3. Since `dev` and `production` flavors are not going to have Huawei dependencies now, you may get build errors for the Huawei related classes that you use in your app.

For that I create dummy classes with the same packages tree as Huawei, for instance:

app > src > dev > java > com > huawei > hms > analytics > HiAnalytics.kt

```
class HiAnalytics {

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context): HiAnalyticsInstance {
            return HiAnalyticsInstance()
        }
    }
}
```

4. This solves the `Cannot resolve symbol` error when trying to import Huawei classes in your main, dev, or production flavors and you can import those classes anywhere:

```
import com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalytics
```

Now if you change the build variant to `dev`, you should have access to the dummy classes in your app. If you change it to `huawei`, you should be able to access the classes from Huawei dependencies.

Comment: how to avoid conflict of same package name with Java ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 06/04/2022**

Huawei released a new version of their SDK : **3.4.0.300**

**3.4.0.300 (2022-03-04)
New Features**

- Real-time translation: Added Afrikaans to the list of languages
  supported. (Note that this language is available only in Asia,
  Africa, and Latin America.)

**Modified Features**

- ***Deleted the capability of prompting users to install HMS Core (APK).***
- Modified the SDK privacy and security statement. Updated the SDK
- versions of all subservices.

For me, since I've migrated to Google ML Kit, I will wait till August, then I will switch back to Huawei ML Kit to make sure Google will not remove or suspend my apps.

---

**Old answer :**

I used to love the HMS ML kit, but because of this issue, I'm aware that Google will one day completely suspend my apps because I'm using HMS services, and even if Huawei fixes the issue, we'll have to wait 120 days to find out if we're safe.

In my case, I'm using the HMS Segmentation ML Kit. I've just switched to Google Selfie Segmentation ML. I will wait till 120 days have passed and see if the issue is still persisting for other developers. If not, I will switch back to the HMS Kit.

Comment: Hi, @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI
Is Google Selfie Segmentation ML free for use?

Comment: @VIISHRUTMAVANII 100% Free

Comment: Google Selfie Segmentation not working properly for background removing

Comment: Hi, this is a late message. But I'm curious to know if you migrated to Huawei-ML-Kit Again and if there issues you faced from Google.

Comment: @avishakchakroborty yes, you can use Huawei ML kit once again, just make sure you have the latest update

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is to update the dependencies like in this link.

With this update, the ability to prompt users to install HMS Core (APK) has been removed.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hmscore-common-Guides/hmssdk-kit-0000001050042513#section20948233203517

Answer (score 0):

I just use hms push when upload to huawei.
i fixed by commenting hms services in  build.gradle and app/build.gradle when to upload to playstore.
Then, I uncomment if upload to huawei.

```
//apply plugin: "com.huawei.agconnect"

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:5.3.0.304'.
```

Comment: What a bad choice to comment/uncomment build settings. Other answers have better setup.