# HMS About the Device and Network Abuse policy

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

The error message:

> Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Device and Network Abuse policy. We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Huawei Mobile Services SDK SDK which contains code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.
> Given the nature of the SDK, please remove it from the version of your app submitted to the Play Store.

## Gradle files

```kotlin
    dependencies {
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
        implementation "com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-auth-google:1.6.4.300"
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.6'
        implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx:20.1.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0'
        ktlint "com.pinterest:ktlint:0.39.0"
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.4'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0'
        implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.6.1.300'
        implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-auth:1.6.1.300'
        implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-crash:1.4.2.301'
        implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
        implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
        implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:10.12.3'
        implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:fingerprint:2.5.3'
        implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
        implementation 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:6.5.1'
        implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0-alpha02'
        implementation 'com.huawei.hms:base:6.2.0.300'
    
    }
```

---

```kotlin
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.4.1.306'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:3.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

What would I have to change to be accepted in the Google Play store?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I tried everything described here but unfortunately not. Using Google instead of the Huawei service would be very cumbersome, but unfortunately it may stay that way.

Comment: Plugin `agconnect-apms-plugin` should be removed; it's embedded into `agcp` now.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Ensure that the latest HMS Core SDK version is used for your APK. About HMS Core SDK Version Updates kindy refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72474416/13329100).

If you have confirmed that the latest SDK version is used, before submitting a release to Google, please check the apks in all Testing track on Google Play Console(including Open testing, Closed testing, Internal testing). Ensure that the APKs on all tracks(including paused track) have updated to the latest HMS Core SDK.

Comment: Would `com.huawei.hms:base:6.5.0.300` be accepted? For Google Play, this only bloats the package, with libraries which will not be used anyway ...not adding them into the package might be more elegant, at least in my opinion.

Comment: hi@MartinZeitler We don't know about specific Google Play policie, but for `com.huawei.hms:base:6.5.0.300`, It has been tested and verified by developers and can be approved by Google for release.

Comment: There's no official policy concerning bloatware, but it's common sense not to add unnecessary dependencies (those devices which have both GMS and HMS are rather the exception and not the default)... providing alternate implementations also might reduce the overall complexity of the project.