# App is using a non-compliant version of Huawei Mobile Services SDK

Tags: android, google-play-console, huawei-mobile-services

My app is getting rejected again & again without proper description.

Hello everyone
My app got rejected for the 4th time now and without clear explanation as to why.
I will quote what the email I got says:

After a recent review, we found that your app AppNAME (abc.xyz.abc) is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See below for more information about your app’s status and how to correct the issue.
Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Device and Network Abuse policy. **We found your app is using a non-compliant version of Huawei Mobile Services SDK** SDK which contains code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.
Given the nature of the SDK, please remove it from the version of your app submitted to the Play Store.

Affected Version(s):
APK:575

In rejection mail Affected Version(s) mentioned is 575 & the version I uploaded for review which is rejected now is 594 & I have removed every idk's related to Huawei

I am not sure what I have to do in order to get my app approved.
Thanks for everyone helping!

Comment: Try running `./gradlew dependencies` and check all your dependencies if there is something from Huawei sneaking around. Maybe one of your libraries is using HMS without you knowing.

Comment: First of all if you have any huawei dependency then it must be because you are also uploading your app on huawei Stores . You don't have to remove those dependencies just create separate Flavor for huawei taht will solve everything . Further more seems like huawei has already [fixed the issue](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hmscore-common-Guides/hmssdk-kit-0000001050042513#section17370146238) So u can upgrade the dependencies ..

Comment: Hi @hardartcore thanks for suggestion. i tried same but didn't find any dependency using HMS now using the same command

Comment: Please check this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72474416/13329100, Note that If you have confirmed that the latest SDK version is used, before submitting a release to Google, please check the apks in all Testing track on Google Play Console(including Open testing, Closed testing, Internal testing). Ensure that the APKs on all tracks(including paused track) have updated to the latest HMS Core SDK.

Comment: @hardartcore how to use ./gradlew dependcies to check ?